# How to give chmod permissions to the screen for the users of my application, that is mainly used in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Wrote a small shell script to get the path of the screen, and then based on two conditions a path to the screen is created. Following which chmod permissions are given.

screen_path = "$(which screen)"
user_host = "$(hostname)"

```
if [ $"user_host" == *"br"* ] || [ $"user_host" == *"b-r"*]; then
    mkdir -p "$(screen_path)"
    chmod 755 "$(screen_path)"
fi

exit 0
```

Also tried

```
if [ $"user_host" == *"br"* ] || [ $"user_host" == *"b-r"*]; then
    mkdir -p "$(screen_path)"
    chmod 755 "$(screen_path)"
fi

exit 0
```

New to shell scripting, also tried removing the ';' after the if block when '()' are used. Is the syntax right? Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

screen is a single binary on your system. It doesn't point to a screen just a program called screen, `which screen` points to the binary.
To control access of users to a program I would use groups.

1. Make a group `groupadd Group_name`
2. Change group of the file( executable and the ones that will be read) `chgrp Group_name file`
3. Make executable available to group members `chmod g+x executable_file`
4. Make all files he/she will need to read readable by the group `chmod g+r file`
5. Add User & yourself to group `useradd -G Group_name username`